# Best way to Parse XML

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xml-parsing

I am working with a xml file available [here](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/shakemap/us2000a3y4/us/1501736303313/download/grid.xml).

I want to parse and load `LON, LAT, PGA, PGV, MMI, PSA03, PSA10, PSA30, STDPGA, URAT and SVEL` as headers of CSV file.

The `grid_data` element has all values to all these headers in a space delimiter fashion.

I am looking for a `csv file output` like below:

```
LON LAT PGA PGV MMI PSA03 PSA10 PSA30 STDPGA URAT SVEL
-99.6833 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.04 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 363.294
-99.6666 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.06 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 342.531
-99.6500 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.11 0.1 0.02 0 0.65 1 303.783
-99.6333 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.08 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 334.629
-99.6166 38.2891 0.04 0.05 2.15 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 279.535
-99.6000 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.08 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 326.391
-99.5833 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.02 0.08 0.02 0 0.65 1 390.897
-99.5666 38.2891 0.04 0.04 2.08 0.09 0.02 0 0.65 1 346.033
```

Later, I'd use pandas for python to find max PGV value and do my GIS Analysis.

So far this is the code I have:

```
import sys
import traceback
from xml.dom import minidom
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

try:
    print "*"*20 + " The Beginning " + "*"*20

    xml_file_location = r"C:\Users\*****\Downloads\Grids\us2000a3y4_grid.xml"
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml_file_location)
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('grid_field')
    for item in itemlist:
        print (item.attributes['name'].value)



Catch all exception and print to the screen
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print( "Error: %s\n\n" % e )

#Closing script
finally:
    print "*"*20 + " The End " + "*"*20
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: edited the question and pasted the code I have so far.

Comment: are there any errors? what is the output?

Comment: ******************** The Beginning ********************
LON
LAT
PGA
PGV
MMI
PSA03
PSA10
PSA30
STDPGA
URAT
SVEL

******************** The End ********************

Comment: I have no idea how to output to a csv file and parsing grid_data which is in space delimiter format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider simply parsing the *grid_data* node using built-in `etree` and pass it directly into `pandas.read_table` using `StringIO()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from io import StringIO    
import requests as rq

# RETRIEVE URL OBJECT
r = rq.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/shakemap/us2000a3y4/us/1501736303313/download/grid.xml')

# BUILD TREE FROM URL CONTENT
doc = et.fromstring(r.content)

# PARSE <grid_data> TEXT WITH UNDECLARED PREFIX NAMESPACE
data = doc.find('.//{http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/shakemap}grid_data').text

# READ SPACE-DELIMITED STRING INTO DATAFRAME
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\\s+", header=0, 
                   names=['LON','LAT','PGA', 'PGV', 'MMI','PSA03','PSA10','PSA30','STDPGA','URAT','SVEL'])

print(df.head())
#         LON      LAT   PGA   PGV   MMI  PSA03  PSA10  PSA30  STDPGA  URAT     SVEL
# 0 -100.3997  38.1145  0.01  0.01  1.77   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  354.533
# 1 -100.3831  38.1145  0.01  0.02  1.82   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  310.786
# 2 -100.3664  38.1145  0.01  0.01  1.77   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  354.545
# 3 -100.3497  38.1145  0.01  0.01  1.76   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  362.307
# 4 -100.3331  38.1145  0.01  0.01  1.76   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  360.332

print(df.tail())
#             LON      LAT   PGA   PGV   MMI  PSA03  PSA10  PSA30  STDPGA  URAT     SVEL
# 105767 -94.4831  33.2425  0.01  0.01  1.78   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  337.237
# 105768 -94.4664  33.2425  0.01  0.02  1.89   0.03   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  249.221
# 105769 -94.4497  33.2425  0.01  0.02  1.83   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  297.622
# 105770 -94.4331  33.2425  0.01  0.01  1.63   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  500.368
# 105771 -94.4164  33.2425  0.01  0.01  1.77   0.02   0.01    0.0    0.65   1.0  340.302
```

Comment: Thanks @parfait .Not sure how you got the output, but the code fails with this message.
`df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\\s+", header=0, names=['LON','LAT','PGA', 'PGV', 'MMI','PSA03','PSA10','PSA30','STDPGA','URAT','SVEL'])
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: I made this change and it did work `data = unicode(doc.find('.//{http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/shakemap}grid_data').text)`
I still get '\' on my output after URAT values, I mean SVEL values jump to a new line. Do you you what should I be doing to put everything in the same line? Thank you.

Comment: What pandas and python version and OS are your running? Check `print(pd.__version__)` I just copied and pasted exact code in this solution and it worked, no error. Originally, it was posted from a Linux (ubuntu 16) run and now a Windows 7 run. Linux uses pandas 20/Windows pandas 19, both python 3.4.

Comment: I am running Pandas v0.20.2 with Python v2.7.5 on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bit machine.

Comment: Hmmm...this must be a 2.7 issue. Are you using exactly this code or another url request object and xml parser? Is *doc* or *data* empty? Maybe try `BytesIO(data)` with `from io import BytesIO`.

Comment: `BytesIO(data)` did work. But I still get a ` '\'` in the output after URAT and SVEL related data jumps to next line

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue to help. Can you test on a python 3 environment? Consider upgrading if your codebase allows it.

Comment: Thank you. Your code is extremely helpful to me. I am using your code.

Comment: Great to hear. Glad I could help. Happy coding!